# Is any country putting pressure against Saudi Arabia for its human rights violations presently?

Tags: saudi-arabia

> The United States and other Western allies have all but rubber-stamped
> Saudi Arabia’s repression at home and abroad. Repeated U.S. failures
> to hold Saudi Arabia to account for a litany of human rights
> violations has emboldened the Saudi government, allowing it to act
> with unbridled impunity as abuses grow ever more horrifying.
>
> In late August, Human Rights Watch reported in gruesome detail how
> Saudi forces are killing hundreds of migrants, including women and
> children, on the remote, mountainous border with Yemen. Researchers
> documented Saudi border guards using explosive weapons against
> Ethiopian migrants and asylum-seekers attempting to cross into Saudi
> Arabia. The attacks are widespread and systematic.

https://foreignpolicy.com/2023/09/13/saudi-arabia-mbs-biden-ethiopia-refugees/

> There has been no international mechanism mandated to monitor rights
> violations in Yemen, including abuses against migrants, since the
> United Nations Human Rights Council-mandated Group of Eminent Experts,
> was disbanded in 2021 following pressure on Council member states from
> Saudi Arabia and the United Arab Emirates. Yemeni, regional, and
> international civil society groups, including Human Rights Watch,
> continue to call on UN member states to fill this gap with a mechanism
> aimed at monitoring the human rights situation in Yemen, and
> investigating abuses with a view to laying the foundation for
> accountability and redress.

https://www.hrw.org/report/2023/08/21/they-fired-us-rain/saudi-arabian-mass-killings-ethiopian-migrants-yemen-saudi

Is any country putting pressure against Saudi Arabia for its human rights violations presently? I am guessing some European countries might be putting pressure against Saudi Arabia, but I haven't found much of anything that suggests that an UN member is doing anything about it.

Comment: Define *putting pressure*. Does one politician from one country criticizing Saudi Arabia count as *putting pressure*?